# Call to NSData(contentsOfURL:) hangs

Tags: xcode, ios8, nsdata

The following code should get data from a url in Amazon S3:

```
let url = ...
let jsonData: NSData? = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
```

The call to NSData never returns.

I am using the latest XCode 6 beta version (Version 6.1 (6A1046a))

What might be the problem?

Comment: bad internet connection?

Comment: No - i have no problem if i perform GET through postman or any browser app

Comment: The method you've shown isn't a GET request.

Comment: download the data through an NSURLRequest link to tutorial: http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example/